# iPad using multiple masterviewcontrollers in a Splitview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I'm currently working on an iPad split view application that uses CoreData.

Initially the MasterViewController has a selection of Cases presented to the user. When the user selects a Case the details of this Case are shown in the detail view. From hereon you can drill down other objects that are in a 1 to many link with the Case (i.e. Documents connected to the case) using a Tab bar embedded in the DetailView. This all works fine.

However once the user has selected a Case I want to use the screen real-estate from the Master view for new options using:

```
DisplayManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
PersonMasterViewController  *mvc = [[PersonMasterViewController alloc] init];
mvc.comingFromCase = managedObject;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:YES];
```

This all works fine and I get the new list of items of the other master view controller.

So here is my problem. How do I get the Detailview to respond to commands from the new master view controller? In the new Masterviewcontroller I tried stuff like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DisplayManagedObject *selectedObject = comingFromCase;
    [self.detailViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = selectedObject; 
    [self.detailViewController.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But with no result. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Never mind, I'm a complete idiot -_- Since I was calling the Case again from the new controller apparently the page doesn't get refreshed. So I would see no difference. Once I called one of the underlying objects it did show the right information.

Comment: This question still appears as open even though you've got it answered yourself. Please either answer the question and accept your own answer, or consider deleting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I'm a complete idiot -_- Since I was calling the Case again from the new controller apparently the page doesn't get refreshed. So I would see no difference. Once I called one of the underlying objects it did show the right information.